# A polynomial of degree 3 that has three real zeros, only one of which is rational.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

Find a polynomial of degree 3 that has three real zeros, only one of which is rational.

My answer: $(x - \sqrt{2})(x - 3)(x - \pi)$.

Is this correct? It does have two irrational zeros, but I'm not sure if I'm 100% right.

P.S. Can I use a similar technique to come with an expression for the following question: A polynomial of degree 4 that has four real zeros, none of which is rational?

Comment: That'll do it.  To make it harder you might try to find an example that has integer coefficients.

Comment: Can I just expand this expression and then multiply throughout to get the result?

Comment: No, you can't.  $\pi$ is transcendental, so will never be the root of a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: @user331377 Yes that would give a polynomial satisfying the question (but not lulu's supplementary question), but it would be a lot less effort to pick something like $(x-1)(x^2-2)=x^3-x^2-2x+2$

Comment: How about replacing $\pi$ with another irrational number like $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @almagest Yeah, that seems nice too! Thanks. :)

Comment: Well, it would have to be a very particular irrational.  $-\sqrt 2$ works here, but $\sqrt 2$ or $\sqrt 3$ would not.

Comment: And for the PS you might try $x^4-5x^2+6$

Comment: Okay then, so I'll think about your question and if I'm not able to come up with something, I'll contact you here.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen See, how do I come up with something like that **directly**?

Comment: @user331377 Hint: try to solve the equation, by substiuting $y=x^2$.

Comment: @wythagoras Thanks! I used it to solve the equation given by Hagen von Eitzen and it worked!

Comment: A neater one:  $$(x-\sqrt2)(x+\sqrt2)(x+2)$$

Comment: Also $x^3-2x=x(x^2-2)$ whose roots are $0$, $+\sqrt{2}$, and $-\sqrt{2}$. _Edit:_ Ah, I see the accepted answer by Lanier Freeman has this as well.

Comment: In case no one else has already mentioned it: Yes, this same idea can be used for the prompt in your **PS**: $(x+\sqrt{2})(x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{3})(x-\sqrt{3}) = (x^2 - 2)(x^2 - 3)$ will do the trick!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct.

Another way to come up with some is to use the form $x^3-nx \;\;\forall\; n\in\Bbb N \land \sqrt n \notin \Bbb N$ (i.e. where $n$ isn't a perfect square but natural).

For the quartic, consider the equation $x^4-(a+b)x^2+(ab)\;\;\forall \;a,b \in \Bbb N \land \sqrt a, \sqrt b \notin \Bbb N$ (i.e. where $a+b$ is the sum of two non-perfect square natural numbers and $ab$ is their product).

Comment: I got the part about my answer being correct, but the second one... If I take something like $x^3 - 5x$, how do I know that it has only one rational zero?

Comment: $x^3-5x=x(x^2-5)=x(x+\sqrt5)(x-\sqrt5)$

Ergo, $x=0,\pm\sqrt5$

Comment: Ah, got it! I forgot to factor first!

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: Did you mean quartic?

Answer (score 3):

For your question at the end, yes, a similiar technique would work.

If you know $n$ zeroes of a polynomial of degree $n$, then you know all of them, because there are at most $n$ of them. So if you know four irrational zeroes, you know that there are no rational zeroes. In particular, for a degree 4 polynomial, you know that there are no rational zeroes if you know four irrational zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple example
with integer coefficients:

$(x^2-2)(x-1)
=x^3-x^2-2x+2
$.